# Modifying a crontab from a cron job

Tags: python, linux, ubuntu, cron

I have a Python script that runs in several modes. One of those modes monitors certain files, and if those files have been modified, the script restores them. The way I do this is to run the script every minute via cron.

Another cron job exists (actually the same script called with a different argument) to remove the script from the crontab when the scheduled time has elapsed. Initially, I was attempting to work with a crontab in `/etc/cron.d`. The script behaves as expected if executed on the command line, but does not edit the crontab when it is run from cron.

I then switched to writing a temporary file and executing `crontab tempfile` (via `subprocess.Popen`) from the script. This doesn't work either, as the crontab is simply not created. Executing `crontab tempfile` from the commandline and using the temporary file created by the script works as expected.

I can't use the python-crontab library as this is a commercial project and that library is GPLed.

Are there any inherent limitations in cron that prevent either approach from working?

Comment: I've never had problems with cronjobs not being able to modify cronjobs / cron configuration files, as long as they ran as a user with the correct permissions. You might want to let that process log some debug info, or it may be that your 'file restorer' restores the crontab configuration right back to where it was...

Comment: I've specifically made sure the file restorer doesn't touch the crontab. Also, as I said, everything works as expected from the command line.

Comment: Does everything work as expected with `env -i andthenyourcommand`? 'cause otherwise I refer you to my first comment: cronjobs are _not_ limited in editing crontab configurations, don't look for the error there.

Comment: Meh, it turned out to be two cron jobs being launched at the same time and trying to acquire the same PID lock. Solving that fixed the problem. @Wrikken: If you post your comment(s) as an answer I'll accept it.

Comment: I could post is as an answer, but as the both the environment as the fix are kind of narrow and wholly code dependent, and not generally applicable, I'd rather leave the question as 'not generally applicable' and leave it at that, making it fase out of SO naturally. The only thing other people could take from it is: _"yes, cronjobs can alter cronjobs"_, which is an answer to a question usually no asked, and in a minimal test case easily verified (the problem here was the actual script was to elaborate (locking etc.) to verify this simple question).

Answer (score 3):

The GPL is not anti-commercial. python-crontab can be used in commercial products and services. You must only follow the copy-left rules witch state that the actual code itself can't be made proprietary. You can sell it as much as you like, and as the author I encourage you to make money from my work.

Besides that error, it doesn't look like your problem requires python-crontab anyway. You could just open the files yourself and if that doesn't work, it was never going to work with python-crontab anyway.

Comment: I am aware of the GPL's restrictions, and as this is a closed-source project, I wish to comply with the GPL :)

Comment: Chinmay - That is an honourable decision. One only has to make the /actual/ code available. Python libraries aren't compiled in and thus don't effect the rest of one's product licence. If you change /my/ code, then let me know.

Comment: The Python code is going to be "compiled"/wrapped using PyInstaller or something similar. Also, while the code will be fairly easy to get at, I'd rather comply with the spirit of the GPL than the letter. If I don't want the user to see the code (and if I'm taking steps to ensure this), regardless of whether the user _can_, I wouldn't want to use GPL licensed code.

Comment: How to modify a old job? job.command='new-cmd' ?